# Move messages from one IBM MQ Queue to a different MQ Queue based on the expiry(time to live)

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, synchronous

I have a application where I am using IBM MQ in a Pseudo-Synchronous way. I have request Q and Response Q. This will called through service. Now there is a time out period for my service to show the response.
But the actual response can be pushed to the response Q after the timeout also. Now I want to move such all delayed messages(timed out) to a separate message Q, such that they can be consumed by a different process.

Is this is possible through setting by time to live? Is any approach available in IBM MQ for such movement.
Please refer below image for the scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use time to live because the message will expire and be deleted - unless that is what you want.  From your description/picture, it sounds like you want another application to process late responses.

There is nothing in MQ that will move messages older then "x" seconds/minutes to another queue.  You will need to write a program to do that.  If you write a program, make sure you do the move under a unit of work.

There are several commercial programs that can do it:  (1) GUI program: [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) and (2) Command Line (shell): [MQ Batch Toolkit](https://capitalware.com/mqbt_overview.html).

Comment: Well dmpmqmsg would also do it, and that comes with MQ.

Comment: @Roger the problem with a program is if i use a new listener on the queue, there is no way to differentiate live message from old messages, so there will a chance that my live messages are also picked up by the new listener which potentially create more timeouts to my original listener

Comment: @SivaRam there is a difference between browse (non-destructive) and destructive get.  If you correctly write the code then it is not a problem.  The 2 programs I listed will not interfere.  They browse the queue, if a message is older than  "x" seconds/minutes, then destructive get the move and put it in the other queue under a unit of work.